# How to copy the names of the subfolders in a folder, so to use them in a batch program (command line)?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, directory, versioning

I need to check the files of a versioned system. To do that, I need to write a batcha program so to compare the contents of several folders containing the repositories.
So, my question is: how can I "read" the names of all the subfolders inside a folder, so to use these names later to find subfolders having the same names in a different repositories?
I suppose I may use DIR to print on the screen a list of these names but I don't know how to write it on a text file and then read it. Moreover, I should edit this kind of list, anyway.
Any suggestions or new ideas to solve this problem?

I thank gratefully who ever will answer.

Comment: `dir`has several useful options. I suggest starting with `/ad /s /b`. Use redirection `>` to write to a file. Use `set /p` or `for` to read from file. See `dir /?`, `set /?`, `for /?`

Comment: ... and [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will read your link soon. I was asking myself, is it possible to use a Perl program to "execute" also DOS commands?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you can get the subfolders using [batch file from perl](https://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/773895-how-call-batch-file-execution-perl-script) as follows:

```
system("start C:\\Temp\\mybatchfile.bat");
```

or you might try to pass your command suggested by @Stephan straight to system and try to handle what it is returned.